# SVN folders when packaging Visual C# Express project

Tags: c#, .net, svn, msbuild, visual-c#-express-2010

I am slightly new to .net development, so bear with me here.

I created a blog project in the .net MVC 3 framework using Visual C# 2010 Express, and everything works great.

I also committed the project to a project locker account to share it with some guys from work.

Now when I am trying to package the project for IIS on my local machine, I am getting errors that it can't delete the SVN folders (Which makes sense of course).

I spent forever looking at places that said to add

But, I have no idea what this means, much less where to add it!

I would appreciate the help in figuring out what I need to do to skip those darn svn directories...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a package from an SVN Export, which is basically a copy of your project with all svn folders/files removed.

Do an SVN Export to a new folder when ready to create a package, and use that folder instead of your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

There's a command `svn export`. It is similar to the `svn checkout` command, but it doesn't create all those `.svn` folders. See the on line Subversion Manual on [Fetching Older Repository Snapshots](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.snapshots).